# Block bots searching for vulnerabilities

Tags: security, wordpress, bots

I downloaded a Wordpress plugin that emails me any time my site serves a 404 error. Last night I got about 1000 emails from bots searching for

/wp-content/plugins/(X name of popular plugin)/timthumb.php

where `timthumb.php` is a popular plugin that had a zero-day vulnerability a few weeks ago, so the traffic is searching my site for vulnerabilities that can be hacked. I don't have timthumb installed, but I **really** don't want this traffic - is there an easy way to block it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml) and [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess5.shtml) page to blacklist all the bots that were logged through your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not something that can be fully stopped.   Instead you should focus on making sure your system is fully updated,  and configured correctly.

Some vulnerability scans and exploits can be stopped using a Web Application Firewall like [PHPIDS](https://phpids.org/) or [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/).  However these security measures won't stop bots from looking for vulnerable files like,  phpmyadmin, fckeditor or the new timthumb.php remote code execution vulnerability.